# Run pdftk in JSP

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, pdftk

I have array value that store pdf filename in jsp page print.jsp
I want to merge the pdf before it can be print.

Here my code:

```
<%
    try
    {
        String[] ids=request.getParameterValues("list");
        for (String id:ids)
        {
            System.out.print(id);
        }

        //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdftk" +id+ "cat output output.pdf");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("fail");
    }
%>
```

How do I write array value to fill up the pdftk command. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is what you need...

```
try {
    String[] ids = request.getParameterValues("list");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String id : ids) {
        sb.append(" "+id);
        System.out.print(id);
    }

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdftk" + sb.toString() + " cat output output.pdf");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("PDF fail to merge");
}
```

Comment: It really works, some correction space in 'sb.append(" "+id)' need to add. Thank for helping me.